# Tablet Genesis 7240 + Android + Bit Web Server dont work

Tags: web-server

I buyed a table ***GENESIS 7240 + Android 4.0.3*** and I've installed the app named [Bit Web Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb) -- but it is not working correcly, not starting.

The App works fine on my Galaxy Note, That proves Its not a problem with the app,  but we need it working in my GENESIS tablet.

ERROR: when I access the address `http://localhost:8080`, says it can not access:

> Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection

====================================================================

The bug was resolved.
Restarting the tablet with Wifi disabled and then start the app, thats it.

Comment: We're going to need more information in order to effectively help you. What do you mean by "not working"? "NGO"? Non-Government Organization? How is that germane to the question?

Comment: I'm work on a Non-Government Organization NGO.

Comment: I teach to 20 students, will install the BIT WEB SERVER, on tablets Model: GENESIS 7240.

Comment: We would like to help you. Really. But you haven't added any information that will help us help you. That you're in an NGO has no bearing on the problem. What we _really_ need is for you to [edit] your question to tell us what "not working" means. What _is_ it doing? What messages are you receiving? What have you tried? (I recognize we probably have a language barrier here.)

Comment: As for the "language barrier": use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) if you can't help it. You see, we try to make the best out of it, even improving your *question's* spelling and phrasing. But as Al wrote: We need more details in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Very tanks for all help.
I've posted the images of aplications and the errors.

Comment: i've try a lot of things but, no success

Comment: It's works now. have to restart without wifi. and then start the aplication. thats all.